Displaying Irrelevant Sensor Data in FIWARE Orion When Using IoT Agent-JSON and Mosquitto
I am developing an IoT application using FIWARE IoT Agent-JSON and Mosquitto. I create test devices, assign sensors to these devices, and publish data for these sensors via Mosquitto. I can correctly see the attributes of the sensors connected to the devices in the IoT Agent's iotagentul.devices and iotagentul.EysDevices tables in MongoDB. However, in the orion-acd table in the Orion Context Broker, I see all the sensor attributes published via Mosquitto, while I only want to see the attributes of the sensors I have connected to the devices.
In Orion Context Broker, I only want to see the attributes of the sensors connected to the devices. Sensor attributes published via Mosquitto but not connected to the devices also appear in this table. I'm curious about the reason and solution to this situation.
Configuration Details:
Docker-compose.yml file:
version: "3.8"
services:
  # Orion is the context broker
  orion:
    image: fiware/orion:3.7.0
    hostname: orion
    container_name: fiware-orion-pms
    networks:
      - default
    expose:
      - "${ORION_PORT}"
    ports:
      - "${ORION_PORT}:${ORION_PORT}" # localhost:1026
    command: -dbhost $IP_ADDRESS:27030 -dbuser $DB_USER -dbpwd $DB_PWD -dbAuthDb admin -db orion -logLevel DEBUG
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail -s http://orion:${ORION_PORT}/version || exit 1
      interval: 5s
    restart: always
    labels:
      maintainer: ino
      description: fiware-orion
      project: pms
      version: v1.0.0
      type: fiware
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5' # maksimum 0.5 CPU çekirdeği
          memory: 512M # maksimum 512 megabayt bellek 
    logging:
      driver: "json-file" # Here, we're using the json-file driver for logging
      options:
        max-size: "1g" # Set the maximum size for a log file (e.g., 1 GB)
        max-file: "5" # Set the maximum number of log files to keep         
  iot-agent:
    image: fiware/iotagent-json
    hostname: iot-agent
    container_name: fiware-iot-agent-pms
    networks:
      - default
    expose:
      - "${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}"
    ports:
      - "${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}:${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}" # localhost:4041
    environment:
      - IOTA_CB_HOST=${IP_ADDRESS} # name of the context broker to update context
      - IOTA_CB_PORT=1026 # port the context broker listens on to update context
      - IOTA_NORTH_PORT=4041
      - IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE=mongodb #Whether to hold IoT device info in memory or in a database
      - IOTA_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG # The log level of the IoT Agent
      - IOTA_TIMESTAMP=true # Supply timestamp information with each measurement
      - IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=v2 # use NGSIv2 when sending updates for active attributes
      - IOTA_AUTOCAST=true # Ensure Ultralight number values are read as numbers not strings
      - IOTA_MONGO_USER=$DB_USER 
      - IOTA_MONGO_PASSWORD=$DB_PWD
      - IOTA_MONGO_AUTH_SOURCE=admin  
      - IOTA_MONGO_HOST=$IP_ADDRESS # The host name of MongoDB
      - IOTA_MONGO_PORT=27030 # The port mongoDB is listening on
      - IOTA_MONGO_DB=iotagentul # The name of the database used in mongoDB
      - IOTA_MQTT_HOST=$MQTT_HOST # The host name of the MQTT Broker
      - IOTA_MQTT_PORT=1883 # The port the MQTT Broker is listening on to receive topics
      - IOTA_DEFAULT_RESOURCE= # Default is blank. I'm using MQTT so I don't need a resource
      - IOTA_PROVIDER_URL=http://iot-agent:${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}
      - IOTA_DEFAULT_TRANSPORT=MQTT
    healthcheck:
      interval: 5s
    restart: always
    labels:
      maintainer: ino
      description: fiware-orion-agent-json
      project: pms
      version: v1.0.0
      type: fiware
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.5' # maksimum 0.5 CPU çekirdeği
          memory: 512M # maksimum 512 megabayt bellek  
    logging:
      driver: "json-file" # Here, we're using the json-file driver for logging
      options:
        max-size: "1g" # Set the maximum size for a log file (e.g., 1 GB)
        max-file: "5" # Set the maximum number of log files to keep        

networks:
  default:
    labels:
      org.fiware: 'fiware-networks-pms'
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.50.1.0/24

Sample record in iotagentul.devices table:
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "665ee84cfc6591f112df952a"
  },
  "lazy": [],
  "active": [
    {
      "name": "Current_L1",
      "type": "Double",
      "object_id": "Current_L1"
    }
  ],
  "commands": [],
  "staticAttributes": [
    {
      "name": "refStore",
      "type": "Relationship",
      "value": "urn:ngsi-ld:pa_DEVICE1:001"
    }
  ],
  "creationDate": {
    "$date": "2024-06-04T10:11:24.071Z"
  },
  "id": "PA_DEVICE1",
  "type": "pa",
  "name": "PA_DEVICE1",
  "service": "acd",
  "subservice": "/pa/DEVICE1",
  "internalId": null,
  "transport": "HTTP",
  "polling": true,
  "__v": 1,
  "apikey": "acd_PA_DEVICE1",
  "subscriptions": []
}

Sample record in orion-acd table:
{
  "_id": {
    "id": "PA_DEVICE1",
    "type": "pa",
    "servicePath": "/pa/DEVICE1"
  },
  "attrNames": [
    "refStore",
    "Current_L1",
    "Voltage_UL1_N",
    "Voltage_UL2_N",
    "Voltage_UL3_N",
    "Current_L2",
    "Current_L3",
    "Total_Consumed_Energy",
    "Total_Power_Factor",
    "Total_Reactive_Power",
    "Total_Apparent_Power",
    "Total_Active_Power",
    "TimeInstant"
  ],
  "attrs": {
    ...
  },
  "creDate": 1717495904.300415,
  "modDate": 1717583504.3732698,
  "lastCorrelator": "ce017f3a-2326-11ef-b4d0-0242ac320102"
}

Question 1: What should I do to prevent sensor attributes that come via Mosquitto and are not connected to devices from appearing in the Orion table?
Quesiton2 :What changes do I need to make to the IoT Agent or Orion configuration to resolve this issue?
I would welcome any help. Thanks!

Not sure if I'm understanding it correctly (btw you should report via IotAgent and NGSIv2 API no mongoDumps), but if you only want to propagate provisioned active and static attrs (Current_L1 and refStore) you may use the explicitAttrs option at group or device configuration.
https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/doc/api.md#explicitly-defined-attributes-explicitattrs
With explicitAttrs = true just provisioned attrs will be propagated. By default every measure gets propagated to the NGSI interface (you may change this default behavior via general config).
In order to create or modify a Group or a device use the provison API (where explicitAttrs is a firstlevel key):
https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/doc/api.md#config-group-api

You have correctly understood my issue. Thank you for answer.
When using Fiware IoT Agent JSON version 1.26.0, this issue does not occur; only the active sensors are written to Orion. However, when I upgrade to Fiware IoT Agent JSON version 3.3.0, all sensors are written to Orion instead of only the active ones.
The phrase "explicitAttrs = true değeri nereye eklemeliyim" translates to "Where should I add the 'explicitAttrs = true' value?

I'd added an API link to the documentation.
